# Como fazer um SELECT puxar qtde ou peso do sql para uma só coluna no grid dependendo do cadastro?

Tags: c#, sql

Estou com a seguinte duvida, criei uma tabela de estoque no sql para embalagens e matérias primas, com cadastro no mesmo formulário.
Criei uma linha para peso e outra para qtde no sql.
E criei um grid com uma só coluna  "qtde/peso"
Quero que em um combobox selecionado por qtde ou peso, busque na tabela especifica do sql e traga na mesma coluna do grid.
Só que não consigo fazer esse select, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você só precisa obter os dois valores, `qtde` e `peso`, e concatenar eles da maneira que preferir. Você utiliza algum framework para acessar o banco ou usa `sql` puro? Se for `sql` puro, qual é o banco de dados da sua aplicação?

Comment: sql , e eu quero ou puxar peso ou qtde , dependendo da especificação do combobox (peso ou qtde). Não quero junta-las.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi sua pergunta e o seguinte:
Voce citou dependendo do cadastro entao suponho que tem algum campo informando a unidade desse produto.
Nao sei como está a estrutura das suas tabelas...
mas isso deve te dar uma ideia de como deve ser.

```
SELECT 
CODIGO,
DESCRICAO,
CASE PRODUTO.UNIDADE
     WHEN 'PESO' THEN PRODUTO.PESO
     WHEN 'QTDE' THEN PRODUTO.QTDE
     END AS QTDE_PESO


FROM PRODUTO
WHERE
//SUAS CONDICOES
```

Comment: muitissimo obrigado